# Sharded concurrency for Cloud Tasks

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tasks

Google Cloud Tasks queues have a [`maxConcurrentDispatches`](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/configuring-queues#rate) parameter that specifies the number of tasks that can execute concurrently for a queue.

Now let's say I have an operation is performed on a user, and any number (with an upper limit) of operations can execute at the same time, but only one at a time per user (e.g. to reduce database contention).

As far as I can imagine, I have two options

1. Specify `maxConcurrentDispatches: 1` so that only one operation can run at a time. However with many thousands of users, this will not scale, especially if it is a long-running operation. The operation throughput will be too slow.
2. Create many different queues, one for each user, each with `maxConcurrentDispatches: 1`, so that any number can execute at the same time but one for each user. However I'm concerned that this too will not scale well. It will become a burden to maintain hundreds of thousands if not millions of queues (what happens if I need to pause all the queues, or change their configuration?). Also I cannot set an upper bound on overall concurrency. Can Cloud Tasks even support a potentially unlimited number of queues?

How should I implement this scenario on Google Cloud Platform? Is there another messaging service that could use, or a design decision that I am overlooking?

Comment: How long take y our task to complete?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere normally in the order of several seconds. Actually it could be any type of operation being performed on a user, some short some long, some frequent high throughput, some infrequent. The point is to abstract the task itself and enforce concurrency limits due to contention.

Comment: Do you use special feature of Cloud Task (delay for instance?

Comment: Not really. It's just convenient because we are running on GCP.

Answer (score 1):

You could use PubSub instead of Cloud Task. Configure the HTTP push subscription to perform the call to the endpoint (as Cloud Task do today).

The trick here is to use an [ordering key](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/ordering). Set the UserID as ordering key and like that the next message for this userID won't be delivered until the current one has not been acknowledged.

Many message will be delivered in the same time as long as they don't have the same ordering key

The "problem" (if it's one): the message will be unqueued in the same order as they are created (FIFO)

Comment: Ah ok I had not considered this thanks. The FIFO behaviour may be a problem, effecively blocking all following tasks from being delivered if there is an error with one task. In some specfic scenarios this may even be desired, but as an abstract task queue it may be a problem... With Cloud Tasks, retries can interleave.

Comment: You can add retries and dead letter topic (after at least 5 retries)

Answer (score 0):

You can [specify `name` attribute when creating a task](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/samples/cloud-tasks-taskqueues-naming-tasks#cloud_tasks_taskqueues_naming_tasks-python), and submitting task with identical name again will fail with `ALREADY_EXISTS` error. So if you will use ID of the user in the task name, you can roughly get one task per user.

This has however a few disadvantages. When you specify the name, the tasks dispatching might have increased latency (because duplicate names need to be checked). And you cant reuse the task name for some time after the previous task has finished successfully. I dont know the exact time, but it's in scale of minutes, please check the docs.

Workaround for the latter issue could be some kind of counter for each user and add it to the task name, or maybe use some timestamp (ie. if user can send one task a minute then use combination of `userID` + `currentMinuteTimestamp()`?

Comment: Up to 4hrs delay for task name reuse https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.locations.queues.tasks/create#request-body

Comment: then (if you'd really go with this approach) use some rounded-up timestamp beside the username as suggested.

Comment: Hmm this would function more as a task-creation throttle than a delivery concurrency limit. Retries on failed tasks could still run at the same time. And a task may not have finished running before the next is created if the timestamp bucket is too short.

Comment: And the process of creating a task could itself become a long-running process. The process would look like: inside a while loop keep retrying to create the task with an incrementing timestamp bucket until one succeeds (and also set a schedule time on the task corresponding to the time bucket). If several processes happen to be creating tasks, then it could take a while to "capture a bucket".

Comment: Then you have to keep track of the user activity elsewhere? Eg. use Redis (Memorystore) to keep track of last user activity which will be deleted when task finishes (+automatic expiration as a prevention of "deadlock"). If other task will try to run for the same user it will check Redis, notice a record for given user is there already, so it will retry later (either by raising exception in the task which will reschedule it, or creating a new task with the same payload and some delay to not start immediately). Or maybe PubSub could be somehow an option? idk.